# Iterate over list of lists and deduce a final list so that group by can be done on each element of final list in python

Tags: python, list

I am having a list of lists like below

```
lst1 = [['sg'], ['sci'], ['op1', 'op2', 'op3'], ['pop1', 'pop2', 'pop3'], ['pn'], [['on'], ['pcat1', 'pcat2', 'pcat3'], ['oci']]]
```

I want to iterate over this list of lists (lst1) and get the result like below list of tuples or list of lists

```
[('sg',), ('sg', 'sci'), ('sg', 'op1'), ('sg', 'op1', 'op2'), ('sg', 'op1', 'op2', 'op3'), ('sg', 'pop1'), ('sg', 'pop1', 'pop2'), ('sg', 'pop1', 'pop2', 'pop3'), ('sg', 'pn'), ('sg', 'on', 'pcat1', 'pcat2', 'pcat3', 'oci'), ('sg', 'on'), ('sg', 'pcat1'), ('sg', 'pcat1', 'pcat2'), ('sg', 'pcat1', 'pcat2', 'pcat3'), ('sg', 'oci')]
```

**Explanation:**

- first element of the lst1 is master element. It will be there with each tuple.
- If the element is list with one element (like ['sci']) then it is added with master element and formed group (like [('sg', 'sci')])
- If the  element of the lst1 is list with more than one value but not nested list (like ['op1', 'op2', 'op3']) then each element will be forming a group (like [('sg', 'op1'), ('sg', 'op1', 'op2'), ('sg', 'op1', 'op2', 'op3')]).
- If the element of the lst1 is list of lists (like [['on'], ['pcat1', 'pcat2', 'pcat3'], ['oci']]) then that is flattened and formed one group (like [('sg', 'on', 'pcat1', 'pcat2', 'pcat3', 'oci')]) and all other individual groups as above (like [('sg', 'on'), ('sg', 'pcat1'), ('sg', 'pcat1', 'pcat2'), ('sg', 'pcat1', 'pcat2', 'pcat3'), ('sg', 'oci')])

Answer (score 0):

```
lst1 = [['sg'], ['sci'], ['op1', 'op2', 'op3'], ['pop1', 'pop2', 'pop3'], ['pn'], [['on'], ['pcat1', 'pcat2', 'pcat3'], ['oci']]]

master=lst1[0]
non_masters=lst1[1:]


def appendMasterSimple(item):
    lists_to_return=[]
    for i in range(0,len(item)):
        lists_to_return.append(master+item[0:i+1])
    return lists_to_return

def appendMasterEmbedded(item):
    lists_to_return=[]
    flat_list=[]
    for sublist in item:
        flat_list.extend(sublist)
    lists_to_return.append(master+flat_list)
    for sublist in item:
        lists_to_return.extend(appendMasterSimple(sublist))
    return lists_to_return

output=[]
for item in non_masters:
    if type(item[0])==list:
        output.extend(appendMasterEmbedded(item))
    else:
        output.extend(appendMasterSimple(item))
```

Edit: Actually your specs call for output=master+output at the very end if you want ['sg'] to be in the front.

Comment: Thanks @D. Kupra
I had one change too in 4th point, like 

If the element of the lst1 is list of lists (like [['on'], ['pcat1', 'pcat2', 'pcat3'], ['oci']]) then that is flattened and formed one group (like [('sg', 'on', 'pcat1', 'pcat2', 'pcat3', 'oci')]) and all other groups for nested list with len > 1 (like [('sg', 'pcat1'), ('sg', 'pcat1', 'pcat2'), ('sg', 'pcat1', 'pcat2', 'pcat3')])

Comment: I'm pretty sure the above meets that specification. Test it. Just call 'output' at the end and see what reads out. Again, if you need ['sg'] at the front, just add output=master+output